# Invalid argument(s) (input): Must not be null - Flutter

Tags: flutter, infinite-scroll

Am building a movies App where i have list of posters loaded using TMDB using infinite_scroll_pagination 3.0.1+1  library. First set of data loads good but after scrolling and before loading second set of data i get the following Exception.

```
"Invalid argument(s) (input): Must not be null"
```

While manual debugging i found exception occurs at `results = Movie.fromJson(jsonMap).results;` in `services.dart` (Movie model file). Any help would be appreciated.

**movie_page.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:infinite_scroll_pagination/infinite_scroll_pagination.dart';
import 'package:zlikx/services.dart';

import 'movies.dart';

class MoviesPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MoviesPage> createState() => _MoviesPageState();
}

class _MoviesPageState extends State<MoviesPage> {
  static const _pageSize = 20;
  final PagingController<int, Result> _pagingController = PagingController(firstPageKey: 1);

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('insideinit');
    _pagingController.addPageRequestListener((pageKey) {
      _fetchPage(pageKey);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchPage(int pageKey) async {
    try {
      final newItems = await Services().fetchmovies(pageKey);
      print('newItems.length' + newItems.length.toString());
      final isLastPage = newItems.length < _pageSize;
      if (isLastPage) {
        print('inside is last page');
        _pagingController.appendLastPage(newItems);
      } else {
        print('pageKey' + pageKey.toString());
        final nextPageKey = pageKey + 1;
        print('nextPageKey :' + nextPageKey.toString());
        _pagingController.appendPage(newItems, nextPageKey);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _pagingController.error = error;
      print('Paging Error: ' + error.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () => Future.sync(
          () => _pagingController.refresh(),
        ),
        child: PagedGridView(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.5),
          pagingController: _pagingController,
          builderDelegate: PagedChildBuilderDelegate<Result>(
            itemBuilder: (context, result, index) {
              return Image.network(
                'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + result.posterPath,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              );
            },
          ),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
        ),
      );

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pagingController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**services.dart**

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'movies.dart';

class Services {
  static const String movie_url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=[KEY_HIDDEN]&language=en-US&page=1";
  static const String popular_movies = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=[KEY_HIDDEN]b&language=en-US&page=";

  Future<Movie> getMovies() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var moviesModel;

    try {
      var response = await client.get(Uri.parse(movie_url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);

        moviesModel = Movie.fromJson(jsonMap);
      }
      // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    } catch (Exception) {
      print(Exception.toString());
      return moviesModel;
    }

    return moviesModel;
  }

  Future<List<Result>> fetchmovies(int pageKey) async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var results;
    print('Inside fetchmovies');
    try {
      print('pageKey: ' + pageKey.toString());
      var urlToHit = Uri.parse(popular_movies + pageKey.toString());
      print(urlToHit);
      var response = await client.get(urlToHit);
      print('response.body: ' + response.body.toString());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var jsonString = response.body;
        var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
        print('jsonMap: ' + jsonMap.toString());
        results = Movie.fromJson(jsonMap).results;
        print('results' + results.toString());
      } else {
        print('response.statusCode: ' + response.statusCode.toString());
      }
      // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
    } catch (Exception) {
      print('fetch movies Exception ' + Exception.toString());
      return results;
    }

    return results;
  }
}
```

My model class **movies.dart**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final movie = movieFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Movie movieFromJson(String str) => Movie.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String movieToJson(Movie data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Movie {
    Movie({
        this.page,
        this.results,
        this.totalPages,
        this.totalResults,
    });

    int page;
    List<Result> results;
    int totalPages;
    int totalResults;

    factory Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Movie(
        page: json["page"],
        results: List<Result>.from(json["results"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
        totalPages: json["total_pages"],
        totalResults: json["total_results"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "page": page,
        "results": List<dynamic>.from(results.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "total_pages": totalPages,
        "total_results": totalResults,
    };
}

class Result {
    Result({
        this.adult,
        this.backdropPath,
        this.genreIds,
        this.id,
        this.originalLanguage,
        this.originalTitle,
        this.overview,
        this.popularity,
        this.posterPath,
        this.releaseDate,
        this.title,
        this.video,
        this.voteAverage,
        this.voteCount,
    });

    bool adult;
    String backdropPath;
    List<int> genreIds;
    int id;
    String originalLanguage;
    String originalTitle;
    String overview;
    double popularity;
    String posterPath;
    DateTime releaseDate;
    String title;
    bool video;
    double voteAverage;
    int voteCount;

    factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        adult: json["adult"],
        backdropPath: json["backdrop_path"],
        genreIds: List<int>.from(json["genre_ids"].map((x) => x)),
        id: json["id"],
        originalLanguage: json["original_language"],
        originalTitle: json["original_title"],
        overview: json["overview"],
        popularity: json["popularity"].toDouble(),
        posterPath: json["poster_path"],
        releaseDate: DateTime.parse(json["release_date"]),
        title: json["title"],
        video: json["video"],
        voteAverage: json["vote_average"].toDouble(),
        voteCount: json["vote_count"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "adult": adult,
        "backdrop_path": backdropPath,
        "genre_ids": List<dynamic>.from(genreIds.map((x) => x)),
        "id": id,
        "original_language": originalLanguage,
        "original_title": originalTitle,
        "overview": overview,
        "popularity": popularity,
        "poster_path": posterPath,
        "release_date": "${releaseDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${releaseDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${releaseDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "title": title,
        "video": video,
        "vote_average": voteAverage,
        "vote_count": voteCount,
    };
}
```

**Console output**

```
I/flutter (14202): pageKey: 2
I/flutter (14202): https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=9b31264aec7cd32ff6ff94ebceecb01b&language=en-US&page=2
I/flutter (14202): response.body: {"page":2,"results":[{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/70AV2Xx5FQYj20labp0EGdbjI6E.jpg","genre_ids":[28,80],"id":637649,"original_language":"en","original_title":"Wrath of Man","overview":"A cold and mysterious new security guard for a Los Angeles cash truck company surprises his co-workers when he unleashes precision skills during a heist. The crew is left wondering who he is and where he came from. Soon, the marksman's ultimate motive becomes clear as he takes dramatic and irrevocable steps to settle a score.","popularity":642.634,"poster_path":"/YxopfHpsCV1oF8CZaL4M3Eodqa.jpg","release_date":"2021-04-22","title":"Wrath of Man","video":false,"vote_average":8,"vote_count":308},{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/7HtvmsLrDeiAgDGa1W3m6senpfE.jpg","genre_ids":[12,16,10751],"id":681260,"original_language":"en","original_title":"Maya the Bee: The Golden Orb","overview":"When Maya, a headstrong little bee, and her best friend Willi, rescue an ant princess they find themselves in the middle of an epic b
I/flutter (14202): jsonMap: {page: 2, results: [{adult: false, backdrop_path: /70AV2Xx5FQYj20labp0EGdbjI6E.jpg, genre_ids: [28, 80], id: 637649, original_language: en, original_title: Wrath of Man, overview: A cold and mysterious new security guard for a Los Angeles cash truck company surprises his co-workers when he unleashes precision skills during a heist. The crew is left wondering who he is and where he came from. Soon, the marksman's ultimate motive becomes clear as he takes dramatic and irrevocable steps to settle a score., popularity: 642.634, poster_path: /YxopfHpsCV1oF8CZaL4M3Eodqa.jpg, release_date: 2021-04-22, title: Wrath of Man, video: false, vote_average: 8, vote_count: 308}, {adult: false, backdrop_path: /7HtvmsLrDeiAgDGa1W3m6senpfE.jpg, genre_ids: [12, 16, 10751], id: 681260, original_language: en, original_title: Maya the Bee: The Golden Orb, overview: When Maya, a headstrong little bee, and her best friend Willi, rescue an ant princess they find themselves in the middle of an epic bug battle that will take t
I/flutter (14202): fetch movies Exception Invalid argument(s) (input): Must not be null
I/flutter (14202): Paging Error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (14202): Receiver: null
I/flutter (14202): Tried calling: length
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity](14202): windowFocusChanged hasFocus=false inTouchMode=true
```

**Response Sample**

```
{
  "page": 2,
  "results": [
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/z2UtGA1WggESspi6KOXeo66lvLx.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        878,
        53
      ],
      "id": 520763,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "A Quiet Place Part II",
      "overview": "Following the events at home, the Abbott family now face the terrors of the outside world. Forced to venture into the unknown, they realize that the creatures that hunt by sound are not the only threats that lurk beyond the sand path.",
      "popularity": 690.813,
      "poster_path": "/4q2hz2m8hubgvijz8Ez0T2Os2Yv.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-05-21",
      "title": "A Quiet Place Part II",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.5,
      "vote_count": 58
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/70AV2Xx5FQYj20labp0EGdbjI6E.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        80
      ],
      "id": 637649,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Wrath of Man",
      "overview": "A cold and mysterious new security guard for a Los Angeles cash truck company surprises his co-workers when he unleashes precision skills during a heist. The crew is left wondering who he is and where he came from. Soon, the marksman's ultimate motive becomes clear as he takes dramatic and irrevocable steps to settle a score.",
      "popularity": 899.688,
      "poster_path": "/YxopfHpsCV1oF8CZaL4M3Eodqa.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-04-22",
      "title": "Wrath of Man",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8,
      "vote_count": 367
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/7HtvmsLrDeiAgDGa1W3m6senpfE.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        12,
        16,
        10751
      ],
      "id": 681260,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Maya the Bee: The Golden Orb",
      "overview": "When Maya, a headstrong little bee, and her best friend Willi, rescue an ant princess they find themselves in the middle of an epic bug battle that will take them to strange new worlds and test their friendship to its limits.",
      "popularity": 890.077,
      "poster_path": "/tMS2qcbhbkFpcwLnbUE9o9IK4HH.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-01-07",
      "title": "Maya the Bee: The Golden Orb",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.6,
      "vote_count": 32
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/5Zv5KmgZzdIvXz2KC3n0MyecSNL.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        53,
        80
      ],
      "id": 634528,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "The Marksman",
      "overview": "Jim Hanson’s quiet life is suddenly disturbed by two people crossing the US/Mexico border – a woman and her young son – desperate to flee a Mexican cartel. After a shootout leaves the mother dead, Jim becomes the boy’s reluctant defender. He embraces his role as Miguel’s protector and will stop at nothing to get him to safety, as they go on the run from the relentless assassins.",
      "popularity": 739.328,
      "poster_path": "/6vcDalR50RWa309vBH1NLmG2rjQ.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-01-15",
      "title": "The Marksman",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.4,
      "vote_count": 505
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/jFINtstDUh0vHOGImpMAmLrPcXy.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        27,
        35
      ],
      "id": 643586,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Willy's Wonderland",
      "overview": "When his car breaks down, a quiet loner agrees to clean an abandoned family fun center in exchange for repairs. He soon finds himself waging war against possessed animatronic mascots while trapped inside Willy's Wonderland.",
      "popularity": 700.784,
      "poster_path": "/keEnkeAvifw8NSEC4f6WsqeLJgF.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-02-12",
      "title": "Willy's Wonderland",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.7,
      "vote_count": 227
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/sPeqIdCYvcmeZe5fCu7JgMnf1HL.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        16,
        35,
        878
      ],
      "id": 825597,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Maggie Simpson in The Force Awakens from Its Nap",
      "overview": "In a daycare far, far away… but still in Springfield, Maggie is on an epic quest for her stolen pacifier. Her adventure brings her face-to-face with young Padawans, Sith Lords, familiar droids, Rebel scum, and an ultimate battle against the dark side, in this original short celebrating the Star Wars galaxy.",
      "popularity": 792.587,
      "poster_path": "/2xnf2ZaGXudvgBKPtVXMkNeooh1.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-05-04",
      "title": "Maggie Simpson in The Force Awakens from Its Nap",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.8,
      "vote_count": 49
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/xXHZeb1yhJvnSHPzZDqee0zfMb6.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        53,
        80
      ],
      "id": 385128,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "F9",
      "overview": "Dominic Toretto and his crew join forces to battle the most skilled assassin and high-performance driver they've ever encountered: his forsaken brother.",
      "popularity": 511.888,
      "poster_path": "/bOFaAXmWWXC3Rbv4u4uM9ZSzRXP.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-05-19",
      "title": "F9",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.3,
      "vote_count": 66
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/czHYg6LQ5926OL8wj5kC09pNR12.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        27,
        35
      ],
      "id": 647302,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Benny Loves You",
      "overview": "Jack, a man desperate to improve his life throws away his beloved childhood plush, Benny. It’s a move that has disastrous consequences when Benny springs to life with deadly intentions!",
      "popularity": 708.777,
      "poster_path": "/mQ8vALvqA0z0qglG3gI6xpVcslo.jpg",
      "release_date": "2019-11-21",
      "title": "Benny Loves You",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6,
      "vote_count": 29
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/z8TvnEVRenMSTemxYZwLGqFofgF.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        14,
        28,
        12
      ],
      "id": 458576,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Monster Hunter",
      "overview": "A portal transports Cpt. Artemis and an elite unit of soldiers to a strange world where powerful monsters rule with deadly ferocity. Faced with relentless danger, the team encounters a mysterious hunter who may be their only hope to find a way home.",
      "popularity": 614.349,
      "poster_path": "/1UCOF11QCw8kcqvce8LKOO6pimh.jpg",
      "release_date": "2020-12-03",
      "title": "Monster Hunter",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.1,
      "vote_count": 1672
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/9ns9463dwOeo1CK1JU2wirL5Yi1.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        35,
        10751,
        16
      ],
      "id": 587807,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Tom & Jerry",
      "overview": "Tom the cat and Jerry the mouse get kicked out of their home and relocate to a fancy New York hotel, where a scrappy employee named Kayla will lose her job if she can’t evict Jerry before a high-class wedding at the hotel. Her solution? Hiring Tom to get rid of the pesky mouse.",
      "popularity": 578.077,
      "poster_path": "/8XZI9QZ7Pm3fVkigWJPbrXCMzjq.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-02-11",
      "title": "Tom & Jerry",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.3,
      "vote_count": 1404
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/ovggmAOu1IbPGTQE8lg4lBasNC7.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        878,
        28,
        12,
        53
      ],
      "id": 412656,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Chaos Walking",
      "overview": "Two unlikely companions embark on a perilous adventure through the badlands of an unexplored planet as they try to escape a dangerous and disorienting reality, where all inner thoughts are seen and heard by everyone.",
      "popularity": 571.196,
      "poster_path": "/9kg73Mg8WJKlB9Y2SAJzeDKAnuB.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-02-24",
      "title": "Chaos Walking",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.1,
      "vote_count": 646
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/srYya1ZlI97Au4jUYAktDe3avyA.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        14,
        28,
        12
      ],
      "id": 464052,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Wonder Woman 1984",
      "overview": "A botched store robbery places Wonder Woman in a global battle against a powerful and mysterious ancient force that puts her powers in jeopardy.",
      "popularity": 550.027,
      "poster_path": "/8UlWHLMpgZm9bx6QYh0NFoq67TZ.jpg",
      "release_date": "2020-12-16",
      "title": "Wonder Woman 1984",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.7,
      "vote_count": 5196
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/h9DIlghaiTxbQbt1FIwKNbQvEL.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        12,
        53
      ],
      "id": 581387,
      "original_language": "ko",
      "original_title": "백두산",
      "overview": "A group of unlikely heroes from across the Korean peninsula try to save the day after a volcano erupts on the mythical and majestic Baekdu Mountain.",
      "popularity": 517.126,
      "poster_path": "/zoeKREZ2IdAUnXISYCS0E6H5BVh.jpg",
      "release_date": "2019-12-19",
      "title": "Ashfall",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.4,
      "vote_count": 266
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/z7HLq35df6ZpRxdMAE0qE3Ge4SJ.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        12,
        35
      ],
      "id": 615678,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Thunder Force",
      "overview": "In a world where supervillains are commonplace, two estranged childhood best friends reunite after one devises a treatment that gives them powers to protect their city.",
      "popularity": 531.611,
      "poster_path": "/3mKMWP5OokB7QpcOMA1yl8BXFAF.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-04-09",
      "title": "Thunder Force",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.8,
      "vote_count": 607
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/y0SiXoTLQp93NbLQ4XhgVz18UAS.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        16,
        28,
        14
      ],
      "id": 663558,
      "original_language": "zh",
      "original_title": "新神榜：哪吒重生",
      "overview": "3000 years after the boy-god Nezha conquers the Dragon King then disappears in mythological times, he returns as an ordinary man to find his own path to becoming a true hero.",
      "popularity": 567.388,
      "poster_path": "/6goDkAD6J3br81YMQf0Gat8Bqjy.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-02-06",
      "title": "New Gods: Nezha Reborn",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.6,
      "vote_count": 165
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/fRrpOILyXuWaWLmqF7kXeMVwITQ.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        27,
        53,
        12,
        9648
      ],
      "id": 522444,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Black Water: Abyss",
      "overview": "An adventure-loving couple convince their friends to explore a remote, uncharted cave system in the forests of Northern Australia. With a tropical storm approaching, they abseil into the mouth of the cave, but when the caves start to flood, tensions rise as oxygen levels fall and the friends find themselves trapped. Unknown to them, the storm has also brought in a pack of dangerous and hungry crocodiles.",
      "popularity": 511.564,
      "poster_path": "/95S6PinQIvVe4uJAd82a2iGZ0rA.jpg",
      "release_date": "2020-07-09",
      "title": "Black Water: Abyss",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 5.1,
      "vote_count": 217
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": null,
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        53
      ],
      "id": 385687,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Fast & Furious 10",
      "overview": "The tenth and penultimate installment of the Fast and Furious franchise.",
      "popularity": 469.311,
      "poster_path": "/2DyEk84XnbJEdPlGF43crxfdtHH.jpg",
      "title": "Fast & Furious 10",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 0,
      "vote_count": 0
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/mi76WsBDStlmU1taHXasYh10LEm.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        35,
        18
      ],
      "id": 676842,
      "original_language": "es",
      "original_title": "Después de ti",
      "overview": "Su, a woman whose friends are only men, finds herself forced to follow a series of absurd instructions to overcome the unexpected death of her fiancé.",
      "popularity": 577.181,
      "poster_path": "/vX1XLbrHxpryX9EOWI3akbasz6c.jpg",
      "release_date": "2021-04-08",
      "title": "Instructions for Su",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.8,
      "vote_count": 45
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/kf456ZqeC45XTvo6W9pW5clYKfQ.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        10751,
        16,
        35,
        18,
        10402,
        14
      ],
      "id": 508442,
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Soul",
      "overview": "Joe Gardner is a middle school teacher with a love for jazz music. After a successful gig at the Half Note Club, he suddenly gets into an accident that separates his soul from his body and is transported to the You Seminar, a center in which souls develop and gain passions before being transported to a newborn child. Joe must enlist help from the other souls-in-training, like 22, a soul who has spent eons in the You Seminar, in order to get back to Earth.",
      "popularity": 503.845,
      "poster_path": "/hm58Jw4Lw8OIeECIq5qyPYhAeRJ.jpg",
      "release_date": "2020-12-25",
      "title": "Soul",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.3,
      "vote_count": 6110
    },
    {
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/aMFl4wOPhJ7NVua6SgU9zIJvFSx.jpg",
      "genre_ids": [
        16,
        10751,
        35,
        12,
        10770
      ],
      "id": 755812,
      "original_language": "fr",
      "original_title": "Miraculous World : New York, les héros unis",
      "overview": "During a school field trip, Ladybug and Cat Noir meet the American superheroes, whom they have to save from an akumatised super-villain. They discover that Miraculous exist in the United States too.",
      "popularity": 469.299,
      "poster_path": "/19kfvGktytDZInUmpv3WlaHoTxP.jpg",
      "release_date": "2020-09-26",
      "title": "Miraculous World: New York, United HeroeZ",
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 8.3,
      "vote_count": 707
    }
  ],
  "total_pages": 500,
  "total_results": 10000
}
```

**updated Model**

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final movie = movieFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Movie movieFromJson(String str) => Movie.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String movieToJson(Movie data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Movie {
  Movie({
    required this.page,
    required this.results,
    required this.totalPages,
    required this.totalResults,
  });

  int page;
  List<Result> results;
  int totalPages;
  int totalResults;

  factory Movie.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Movie(
        page: json["page"],
        results: List<Result>.from(json["results"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
        totalPages: json["total_pages"],
        totalResults: json["total_results"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "page": page,
        "results": List<dynamic>.from(results.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "total_pages": totalPages,
        "total_results": totalResults,
      };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    required this.adult,
    this.backdropPath,
    this.genreIds,
    this.id,
    this.originalLanguage,
    this.originalTitle,
    this.overview,
    this.popularity,
    this.posterPath,
    this.releaseDate,
    this.title,
    this.video,
    this.voteAverage,
    this.voteCount,
  });

  bool adult;
  String? backdropPath;
  List<int>? genreIds;
  int? id;
  String? originalLanguage;
  String? originalTitle;
  String? overview;
  double? popularity;
  String? posterPath;
  DateTime? releaseDate;
  String? title;
  bool? video;
  double? voteAverage;
  int? voteCount;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        adult: json["adult"],
        backdropPath: json["backdrop_path"],
        genreIds: List<int>.from(json["genre_ids"].map((x) => x)),
        id: json["id"],
        originalLanguage: json["original_language"],
        originalTitle: json["original_title"],
        overview: json["overview"],
        popularity: json["popularity"].toDouble(),
        posterPath: json["poster_path"],
        releaseDate: DateTime.parse(json["release_date"]),
        title: json["title"],
        video: json["video"],
        voteAverage: json["vote_average"].toDouble(),
        voteCount: json["vote_count"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "adult": adult,
        "backdrop_path": backdropPath,
        "genre_ids": List<dynamic>.from(genreIds!.map((x) => x)),
        "id": id,
        "original_language": originalLanguage,
        "original_title": originalTitle,
        "overview": overview,
        "popularity": popularity,
        "poster_path": posterPath,
        "release_date": "${releaseDate!.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${releaseDate!.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${releaseDate!.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "title": title,
        "video": video,
        "vote_average": voteAverage,
        "vote_count": voteCount,
      };
}
```

Added github link for reference https://github.com/nizamudeenms/ZlikxFlutter/

Comment: Could you provide the full `response.body` since now it gets cut at the second element?

Comment: @mkobuolys Response body with only one item inside result array has been added above.

Comment: I saw that, but the full response is needed. I expect that one of the `results` object contains property that is null, but in your Result model every property is mandatory.

Comment: @mkobuolys Updated full response of Page 2. please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Result` object with ID 385687 you have a property `backdrop_path` being null. Adjust your `Result` object and make the property nullable:

`String? backdropPath;`

Comment: Thanks! I too found it after comapring the JSON's but now to introduce null i have to use min flutter sdk 2.12.0. I did, Now the problem is it is asking to explicitly define all the variable are null or required. how can i avoid this and provide null only to the my variables of choice.

error:  
The parameter 'results' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.

Comment: Just add `required` to your constructor properties that are non-nullable. For the others, you have to mark them as nullable (adding ?). I would recommend you reading more about the null safety in Dart: https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: I have updated my project to null safety and still gives the same error.

Comment: Hard to say what’s wrong without checking the code.

Comment: Added  updated model class at the end of question. please check.

Comment: And where this error comes from (specific line).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233082/discussion-between-nizamudeen-sherif-and-mkobuolys).